# Is "revert the damage" possible? If yes, is it too official?

Tags: phrase-requests

Can "revert damage inflicted" be used in a letter to a friend? Would it sound too official? If yes, what phrase would you use instead of the high-lightened one below?

> Not only did he type all kinds of
>   nonsense and clicked on "Sent" button
>   a few times on that page, he even
>   tried browsing some others forums
>   where I am a member and "provided some
>   input" there too. I did punish him
>   when I came back, but punishing him
>   ***didn't revert all the damage inflicted***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You typically ***repair*** damage:

> ***repair*** (verb, trans.)
>
> - fix or mend (a thing suffering from damage or a fault)
> - make good (such damage) by fixing or repairing it
> - put right (a damaged relationship or unwelcome situation)

*<sup>(New Oxford American Dictionary)</sup>*

Comment: Thank you. Do you think I could drop "*inflicted*" here?

Comment: @brilliant: *inflicted* makes the statement stronger, but can be dropped without change in the meaning

Comment: +1 "repair" is nice. You could also use "undo".

Comment: If the method of repair is to revert, as with some software (VCS, e.g. SVN), then being more specific may be desirable.

Answer (score 6):

The "revert the damage inflicted" may not be a most natural phrase, but is certainly grammatically acceptable and would be understood.

In this particular context, I would probably use *undo*. (Note the other minor changes, which are required for grammatical and logical correctness.)

> I did punish him when I came back, although punishing him didn't undo all the damage inflicted.

Comment: Your modified version has actually changed the meaning because the act of punishment DID take place. Is it possible to keep the original meaning and at the same time use "*undo*"?

Comment: your “other minor changes” completely turned around the meaning of the sentence! @brilliant is saying the child was indeed punished, even though that does not undo the damage.

Comment: @brilliant: yes, *undo* is fine

Comment: @brilliant, F'x: Oops, yes, you're right. I was slightly confused by the unusual phrasing of the original sentence, but I see now. :) Undo is fine in any case.

Answer (score 3):

You could also **reverse** the damage, if the damage is **reversible**.  For example, if you broke my bicycle, I may ask you to **repair** the damage by fixing it, but if you put all my CDs in the wrong order, I may ask you to **reverse** the damage by putting them back in the original order.